# How to open an external URL into new table column upon onclick function?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have few external URLs in left columns of table and onclick I want to open those URLs on right columns of the table. 
This is for angular 6 application.

I have tried, but those URLs either open in new tabs or in same page.

Comment: After clicking, you can display URLs on `iframe`.

Answer (score 0):

If the URL's provides raw data you can do the following:

Write logic to handle the click in the left columns. So browser will not redirect to the external url by himself, but when it is clicked you will fetch the data and load it in the other columns dynamicaly.

You can convert URL`s in the left column to buttons for example or anything you want.

However if the URL`s provde you complete tables with data, html, css.. and you need only to show this in your own page, then you need to understand how iFrame works and can it helps you.

Second approach of course also includes your own logic when the click event occur.